# How to limit type parameters of methods when instantiating traits in Scala

Tags: scala

```
trait A{ 
 def a[K]: Int
}
new A{
  def a[K:SomeTypeClass] = ???
}
```

Is it possible to limit type parameters in methods when implementing a trait in Scala? (edited)

I do not want to through trait parameterization

For example

```
trait Service[V] {
  def save(value: V): Task[Unit]
  def read[K](key: K): Task[V]
}

val dynamoDBService = new Service[Person]{
  def save(value: V): Task[Unit] = ???
  def read[K: DynamoDBFormat](key: K): Task[V] = ???
}

dynamoDBService.read[name]("tom")

dynamoDBService.read[Id]("123-123-123")
```

Comment: Limit them how?

Comment: The interface says that `a` has to work for all possible `K`, making it more restricted would break **Liskov**. Can you tell us more of what you want to do and why?

Comment: What if If I extend A and do an override of method a? I'm trying to Abstract behaviour. I want A to be a repository but it's implementation can give different meaning to K.

Comment: _"What if If I extend A and do an override of method a"_; the class would be abstract and can not be instantiated but I do not see how that is relevant here. - _"but it's implementation can give different meaning to K"_; so maybe you want to move **K** to the trait level, e.g. `trait A[K] { def a: Int }`? It is hard to give an answer if you do not provide more details.

Comment: I have updated my example

Comment: `def save(value: V)` in **dynamoDBService** is wrong, it should be `def save(value: Person)`, the same as in the result of `read`, but anyways. No, you can't do that, because it breaks **Liskov**, like assume you pass a **dynamoDBService** to a function that expects a **Service[Person]** how would that function call `write` if it doesn't know that the `K` has to have that typeclass. Even if it could magically find the typeclass, what if it calls it with a `K` that doesn't have it? You would have a runtime error for something that should have been a compile error, you are breaking **Liskov**

Comment: I would propose something like: `trait Service[K, V]` and `val dynamoDBService = new Service[DynamoKeys, Person]` where **DynamoKeys** need the **DynamoDBFormat** to be instantiated, then you leave the responsibility of creating the keys to someone that knows that the service you will be using is a dynamo one... but then, I would also recommend rethinking if you really have an abstraction here or not, because probably you will never make anything generic on service, every time you would need to know which specific service you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) requires that the implementation of an abstract function must accept all the types that are accepted by the abstract function.

To avoid this you must have a type parameter on the trait so that different implementations have different interfaces and therefore do not have to conform to Liskov.

```
trait A[TypeClass[_]] {

  def a[K: TypeClass]: Int
}

new A[SomeTypeClass] {
  def a[K: SomeTypeClass]: Int = ???
}
```

or

```
trait A {
  type TypeClass[_]

  def a[K: TypeClass]: Int
}

new A {
  type TypeClass[T] = SomeTypeClass[T]

  def a[K: SomeTypeClass]: Int = ???
}
```